# How does Spring MVC handle uncaught exceptions raised in controllers?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, threadpool, uncaught-exception

I need to understand how Spring MVC handles uncaught exceptions if there is no uncaught exception handler explicitly provided by the application. Can a scenario where multiple concurrent requests all of which raise uncaught exceptions impact the Tomcat's thread-pool to leak or get hung?

Comment: No, it can't. You'll just get a 500 error.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, so what you are saying is that Spring MVC does proivde a default Uncaught exception handler that will intercept and provide the 500 response?

Comment: No. If the controller or an advice doesn't deal with the exception, it ends up being thrown by the DispatcherServlet's doXxx() method, and the container responds with 500 error

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@ControllerAdvice`([more details](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/controlleradvice-improvements-in-spring.html)):

For example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = AccessDeniedException.class)
    public ModelAndView accessDeniedError(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        return new ModelAndView("/403");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({SQLException.class,DataAccessException.class})
    public ModelAndView databaseError() {
        ....
    }

    ...

}
```